# How do I write an OR query in Kibana (ElasticSearch)?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Using ElasicSearch's JSON Query DSL through Kibana, how do I retrieve all documents which have:

- `messageTemplate` equals `My message`
- **or**
- `level` equals `Error`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a [Bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-bool-query.html) for that :

> ... If the bool query is a filter context or **has neither must or filter** then at least one of the should queries must match a document for it to match the bool query

```
    POST <your_index>/_search 
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [

              { "match_phrase" : { "messageTemplate" : "My message" } },
              { "term" : { "level" : "Error" } }

          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: `{`s inside `[` are extra, no?

Comment: Thanks! I had to use `match_phrase` instead of `term` to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could type in the Kibana search bar:

```
messageTemplate:"My message" || level:"Error"
```

or

```
messageTemplate:"My message" OR level:"Error"
```